# Best way to check if query mysql table with JSON column if equals a JSON value?

Tags: mysql, json

Hi I have a mysql table with a JSON column. Lets say table name is example_table and JSON column name is json_column and I have a JSON value x that I want to query by.

I was wondering if there is someway to query on the table to see if a value inside example_table that has a json_column value equal to x.

So something like this:

`select * from example_table where json_column=x;`

Example where x is a JSON array.
`select * from example_table where json_column='["12345", "56789"]';`

The above query does not work. I was wondering how I can query the table this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

`select * from example_table where json_column=CAST('["12345", "56789"]' AS JSON);`

Comment: What if the data is stored as ["56789", "12345"]?

Comment: @ChrisStrickland, It's appropriate to treat that as a different JSON value, because JSON arrays are ordered.

Comment: I was just wondering about his expectation.  In JS, for instance, two arrays with identical values can give false for ==, which is an unexpected result to many.  I was curious about his use case.  In some cases creating an array and checking that against the column might be the best way to go, and in some maybe not.

Comment: Consider this fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nCZ9TgKAQqLuaMntqsxLvF/0.  You can also unquote the value and make a string comparison.  It's maybe slightly shorter than the other, but if his use case is slightly more complicated it might not be, since mysql 5.7+ offers shorthands for json_unquote and json_extract.  It really just depends on what he's trying to do and what his expectations are.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStrickland I never considered order and I don't think that will affect my use case but I will keep your solution in mind if that use case does come up.

Comment: RFC says order is preserved but is arbitrary.  So it is dependent on how the data was generated, so I wouldn't count on it unless you have some guarantee about the order.  I'm not saying that the solution from that fiddle is the best one, just that there are inbuilt JSON functions.  I assumed that your use case was more complex, so I didn't offer anything.  If you are trying to compare the whole column and the order is known then string comparison is fine.  See this fiddle, though: while you can't use = you can use RLIKE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nCZ9TgKAQqLuaMntqsxLvF/1, which seems easier